# Java Hotel Reservation

Tags: java, division, modulo

I have to make hotel reservation system, but I am not allowed to use if/else to know if somebody stays longer than a week, because when they stay 7 days the get a discount( the stay 8 nights = 7 days with discount + 1-day normal price). And I haven`t really an idea how to make this (with if I would know it and would be quite easy)

Hope somebody can give me a tip.

That's my code till know:

```
public class HotelReservationSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Amount persons: ");
        int persons = In.readInt();
        System.out.println("Amount days: ");
        int days = In.readInt();
        System.out.println("Meals: ");
        int meals= In.readInt();

        int twinRooms = persons/2 + persons%2;
        System.out.println("Double rooms: " + twinRooms);

        int priceForStay = days*(twinRooms*9500);
        System.out.println("Price for staying: " + priceForStay/100 +"€");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just mathematics then?

Comment: If it's easy, show how you'd do it with an `if`.

Comment: Note: `int twinRooms = (persons + 1) / 2;` is an easier way to calculate the number of rooms.

Comment: you could use ternary operator: `condition ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse()`

Comment: Can `switch` be used as well?

Comment: `(days/7) * discountedPricePerWeek + (days%7) * pricePerDay`

Comment: I don't see the problem to use an `if` there.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer Apart from " I am *not allowed* to use if/else" then. OP is doing an assignment in which if/else is not allowed.

Comment: @AxelH it would give the first 6 days at no discount, but 7 days gets a discount. and 8 days gets 7 days at a discount plus 1 day at the normal day rate.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt ow right, not enough coffee to do math I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Every full 7 days gets a discount. So you can just calculate the number of discounted days with modulo. No conditions needed.

```
int days = 12;
int fullPriceDays = days % 7; // 5
int discountedDays = days - fullPriceDays; // 7
```

Comment: You want `/ 7` not `% 7`, I don't think the intent is to get 5 days free.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @PeterLawrey Both / and % are possible. Depends on how he wants to proceed with price calculation.